# gsutil - Excluding files while synchronize contents of two buckets using regex on windows

Tags: python, regex, windows, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am fetching data from a private Google Cloud Bucket using python's gsutil.

To do so, I'm using rsync, to synchronize two folders.

- Here is the syntax:  `gsutil -m rsync -x 'pattern' src_url dst_url`

Option -m is used for multithreading and option -x is used to exclude files.

The pattern I'd like to exclude is csv files ending in `app_version`.

This is what I've come up with :

`gsutil -m rsync -x '.*app_version\.csv$' gs://pubsite_prod_rev_04681594767840986453/stats/installs/ test/`

But this regular expression pattern doesn't work.
It syncs csv files also.

Can any one please help to make this Regex work?

Comment: Which is it, app_version.csv or just .csv? Please be sure of what it is you want!

Comment: Can you please provide the output of running gsutil version -l  ? I'm wondering if this something related to your OS or Python version, because when I tried this command, gsutil correctly copied only the objects whose names don't end with .csv: gsutil rsync -x '.*\.csv$' gs://my-bucket/t dir

Comment: Running output of  gsutil version -l
`gsutil version: 4.19
python version: 2.7.0
OS: Windows 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment that you ran this command on Windows I tried on Windows and figured out the problem: The single quotes around the regex don't work on Windows, and instead you should use double quotes. The following command correctly excluded the .csv file from being copied:

```
\Python27\python.exe gsutil rsync -x ".*\.csv$" gs://my-bucket .
```